# Possible issues with not assign values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

So I have this piece of code:

```
function HeyHo(test){
  var self = this;

  self.yo;

  if (test > 2) {
    self.yo = {};
  }
}

$('.result').text(new HeyHo(3).yo === undefined)
```

The output is:

```
false
```

As expected, and when the value is less than two the output is:

```
true
```

This is also expected.

But obviously doing this:

```
self.yo;
```

Isn't an assignment or a call. Is there any performance or other issues tied with doing this?

The point is to have the value to start with `undefined`, then conditionally give it a value, so I can then do that check later on in code.

Comment: What are you expecting `self.yo;` to do?

Comment: `Is there any performance or other issues tied with doing this?` Well it's pointless and achieves nothing. You'd get the same effect just by omitting it entirely. Performance wise it probably has little or no effect (it might even be optimized away by some browsers), but since it does nothing, why even bother?

Comment: There is no reason to set `self = this` in this context.

Comment: obviously it is a construed example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But obviously doing this:
>
> ```
> self.yo;
> ```
>
> Isn't an assignment or a call. Is there any performance or other issues tied with doing this?

Yes: It's pointless. :-) It has no effect whatsoever and can simply be removed. All it does is look up the `yo` property on `self` (which won't be there, so the lookup will result in `undefined`) and then throw the value away. In theory doing that unnecessary lookup would be a *really really really small* impact on performance, but you'd have to be doing it a **lot** (like "how many stars in our galaxy" lot) for it to really show up, and that's assuming the JS engine didn't recognize that it could optimize it out.

You also don't need `self`. This code is functionally identical to your version:

```
function HeyHo(test){
  if (test > 2) {
    this.yo = {};
  }
}

$('.result').text(new HeyHo(3).yo === undefined)
```

---

Re your comment:

> I do it, because it is easier to check if an object is undefined than empty, so rather than doing `self.yo = {}` with the possibility of it being populated, I take away that change by having it `undefined` first.

The `self.yo;` line doesn't do anything to the object *at all*, and in particular it doesn't create a `yo` property on it:

```js
function HeyHo1() {
  this.yo;
}
function HeyHo2() {
  this.yo = undefined;
}
var h1 = new HeyHo1();
snippet.log("Does h1 have 'yo'? " + ('yo' in h1 ? 'Yes' : 'No')); // No
var h2 = new HeyHo2();
snippet.log("Does h2 have 'yo'? " + ('yo' in h2 ? 'Yes' : 'No')); // Yes
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you wanted to ensure that the object always had a `yo` property, you'd do this:

```
self.yo = undefined;
```

...as in `HeyHo2` above. That creates the property, with the value `undefined`.

But there's little to no reason to do that in JavaScript, since the result of looking up a property that *doesn't exist at all* is also `undefined`. It's not an error.

But there *can be* reasons for doing this, they're just rare; such as:

- The object is at the top of a long prototype chain and you want to prevent lookup on the property from having to traverse that chain to figure out that the property doesn't exist, by making it exist (with the value `undefined`) on the object
- Some other code might inspect the object to see what its properties are (`for-in` and such), and you want the property name to be there

In those cases, you might want to have `self.yo = undefined;` Other than that, there's basically no need to.

Comment: I do it, because it is easier to check if an object is undefined than empty, so rather than doing `self.yo = {}` with the possibility of it being populated, I take away that change by having it `undefined` first.

Comment: This is obviously an optimisation that I can do, thanks for the heads up.

Comment: @CallumLinington: If it's undefined, it's *undefined*. So don't define it. At all. And it'll be *undefined*.

Comment: @CallumLinington: It's not even an optimization. If you think the `self.yo;` line does **anything** lasting, it doesn't. You might as well write `27;` or `"foo";`. I'm only emphasizing this because it still seems like you think it does something. :-) Omitting completely pointless code isn't an *optimization*, it's...removing pointless code.

Comment: It's not an optimisation in terms of code, like you keep saying, it is something I can omit from my code because, as you keep saying, it's pointless. I think from the many comments I get the picture.

Comment: It's meant to be chance, not change... in my comment